# How do I view my whole character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have played Oblivion and in Oblivion you can see your person on the menu screen. When I go into 3rd person all I see is their back. Is there any way I can see my whole character?

Comment: I don't have Skyrim installed right now but I think holding the 3rd person view button will allow you to rotate the camera freely. Definitely worked in previous ES games.

Comment: Similarly, I would like to be able to play third person zoomed out a bit more, I find it annoying how much of the screen is covered by my character. (Playing on PS3 and would love to fix this.)

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways you can see your whole character

- Leave the game on for a while without moving or touching any of the controls, if you wait long enough, the camera will rotate around your character, allowing you to see your character from all sides and many angles
- To do this method you must sheath your weapons/spells/hands and stand still. Then you will be able to zoom out into 3rd person (clicking left bumper for XBOX360 and default F for pc). Once you are in 3rd person slowly tilt the camera around to see your character from the front.

Answer (score 1):

So if you're on playstation or xbox shealth your weapon and hit R3 or L3, one of the two if you are in first person.

Comment: In its current state, this answer is incoherent and does not appear to answer the question. If you believe that this does answer the question, I suggest cleaning it up and adding further explanation.